# Where do I find free 1950s patterns?

Tags: patterns

Does anyone know of a source for 50s patterns?

Comment: 1950s-era patterns of *what*? Clothing? Wallpaper? General retro styles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FREE - One of the best resources for free and paid retro from the 50's through 70's is [Tack-O-Rama](http://tackorama.net/). Plenty of clip-art, fonts and tiles for backgrounds

Answer (score 3):

Dover publications are the long-time go-to source for historic imagery in reproducible formats:

http://store.doverpublications.com/by-subject-clip-art-and-design-on-cd-rom.html?_s_icmp=XDxPnsR1

Veer also has plenty of stock art collections including patterns:

http://tinyurl.com/43fydv7

Comment: I don't believe that any of those are free.

Comment: Ah, I missed the 'free' part--not that the above are expensive.

Answer (score -1):

Ten seconds of googleing found me this:

http://images.google.com/images?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1236&bih=762&q=free+1950s+patterns&gbv=2&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=

Comment: Not sure they were looking for sewing patterns ;o)